# Control internet connection

Tags: c++, api, qt, internet-connection

I am trying to develop an application (C++/Qt preferably for multi-platform) that controls and filters the data stream entering and leaving the network (mainly internet), and restricts access to certain URLs in the browser.

Is that possible with Qt? If not are there libraries that can do this? Or are there any APIs that I can use to control the connection on the computer?

Comment: Are you talking about socket programming? Do you want to filter data based on tcp/udp data packets ?

Comment: If you have a router can't you just use its filtering capabilities?  Almost all routers have this ability.

Comment: what is socket programming exactly and how can it help me??

Answer (score 2):

To control access to internet, the best possible way is to write your own DNS server and then point the current dns server to self. This although will be very complicated, this is one of the many ways to do it.

Comment: that will be complicated!! but I thinked about developping a proxy server and force the navigator to pass trow this proxy. but a user can just disable that and the navigator will no more use the proxy!! Otherwise, tell more about socket programming??